# Easy way of not overwriting file when output is the same

Tags: python, cmake

I have a C++ code generator in Python that generates many source files.  Most of the time, only one file changes, but because the generators regenerates all of the files, they are all rebuilt.  Is there a way to either get Python to not overwrite the files, or else to get cmak to use a checksum to see what needs to be rebuilt rather than just using the file date?

I was thinking something like this would be easy in Python:  If I could replace

```
with open('blah', 'w') as f:
```

with this:

```
with open_but_only_overwrite_if_total_output_is_different('blah', 'w') as f:
```

What's a nice way of accomplishing that?

Comment: You're asking if cmake or Python can determine if the files should be overwritten __before__ the code has been generated in your Python script?

Comment: No, he's asking if it's possible to avoid changing the modification date of the file in this case, since the build system (CMake) will rebuild the file if the modification date changes, making the build take longer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combining the code and ideas of [Neil G](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718891/easy-way-of-not-overwriting-file-when-output-is-the-same/8719628#8719628), [Petr Viktorin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8720431/190597), [gecco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8718990/190597), and [joel3000](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8719628/190597):

```
import contextlib
@contextlib.contextmanager
def write_on_change(filename):
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as f:
        yield f
        tempname = f.name
    try:
        overwrite = not filecmp.cmp(tempname,filename)
    except (OSError,IOError):
        overwrite = True
    if overwrite:
        shutil.copyfile(tempname,filename)
    os.unlink(tempname)
```

Some little additions (hopefully improvements):

- `shutil.copyfile` only copies the contents of `tempname` into
  `filename`, while preserving metadata like file permissions and file
  ownership.
- `filecmp.cmp` checks the size of the files
  and returns `False` if the sizes don't match. That could be a nice
  speedup if the files are large and one has stuff appended to the
  end. It also reads and compares [bufsize = 8*1024](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/7d87ebbbd718/Lib/filecmp.py#l19) bytes at a time,
  instead of lines at a time. `bufsize` will generally be bigger than a
  line, which would result in fewer reads.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not quite sure why, but when I test this code on /tmp/test.dat with 777 permissions but owned by another user, `shutil.copyfile` succeeds, but `shutil.move` results in OSError.

Comment: `shutil.move` calls `shutil.copystat` which tries to change the atime and mtime. That's not permitted when you don't own the file. Thus, the call to `os.utime` fails. `shutil.copyfile` does not change the metadata, so it works.

Comment: Excellent usage of `yield` and `contextlib.contextmanager`! Great!

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you write our own file-like object like this:

- `__enter__`: Create a temporary file
- `__exit__`: Compare content of temporary file with old file (if exists) If they are not the same, then replace the old file by the temporary file

*This article is quite helpful for understanding the `with` statement: [Understanding Python's "with" statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm)*

Comment: Nice solution. To replace the old file by the temp file, is it possible to somehow point the old file at the temporary file? Instead of reading the tempfile and writing it to the old file

Comment: @robertking yes: [shutil.move](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.move)

Answer (score 3):

Use filecmp - http://docs.python.org/library/filecmp.html .

Write your new files into a tmp directory, compare against your working directory
, and transfer over altered files. Then delete tmp.

Comment: Ah, thanks!  Just when I finished coding up gecco's solution…

Comment: Depends. It would works best on a unix system (as opposed to win). Try it.

Comment: This would be the best solution if `filecmp` accepted file handles rather than filenames.  However, +1, thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: Hmm. NamedTemporaryFile will give you a name to work with. I would think that should work with filecmp. I'm curious. I'll try it when I have time.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'd have to set delete to False and pass the temporary filename to filecmp after I've closed the file. It's not a bad solution, but it would have been nice not to have to close and reopen the file.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to do in Python exactly what cmake does: have the generator check if the input is newer than the output, and only generate if it is.

Here is a snippet I used for something similar:

```
if (os.path.exists(output) and
    os.path.getmtime(source) <= os.path.getmtime(output)):
    print "Generated output %s is up-to-date." % output
    return
```

Comment: There is nothing that says he is using a file on his local filesystem as an input to the generator. In reality, it could be anything.

Comment: The generator is a program, so it's hard to know at run time which output files will be affected by the changes I've made to the program.

Comment: In that case, either implement something along the lines of @gecco's answers. Another option, have your generator write to a StringIO.StringIO. Then write a quick function named `write_if_different(stringio, filename)`