# Nesting Python context managers

Tags: python, contextmanager

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718891/easy-way-of-not-overwriting-file-when-output-is-the-same/8719628#8719628), I defined a context manager that contains a context manager.  What is the easiest correct way to accomplish this nesting?  I ended up calling `self.temporary_file.__enter__()` in `self.__enter__()`.  However, in `self.__exit__`, I am pretty sure I have to call `self.temporary_file.__exit__(type_, value, traceback)` in a finally block in case an exception is raised.  Should I be setting the type_, value, and traceback parameters if something goes wrong in `self.__exit__`? I checked `contextlib`, but couldn't find any utilities to help with this.

Original code from question:

```
import itertools as it
import tempfile

class WriteOnChangeFile:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename

    def __enter__(self):
        self.temporary_file = tempfile.TemporaryFile('r+')
        self.f = self.temporary_file.__enter__()
        return self.f

    def __exit__(self, type_, value, traceback):
        try:
            try:
                with open(self.filename, 'r') as real_f:
                    self.f.seek(0)
                    overwrite = any(
                        l != real_l
                        for l, real_l in it.zip_longest(self.f, real_f))
            except IOError:
                overwrite = True
            if overwrite:
                with open(self.filename, 'w') as real_f:
                    self.f.seek(0)
                    for l in self.f:
                        real_f.write(l)
        finally:
            self.temporary_file.__exit__(type_, value, traceback)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling instances of a context manager inside another context manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24637199/handling-instances-of-a-context-manager-inside-another-context-manager)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easy way to create context managers is with [`contextlib.contextmanager`](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager). Something like this:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def write_on_change_file(filename):
    with tempfile.TemporaryFile('r+') as temporary_file:
        yield temporary_file
        try:
             ... some saving logic that you had in __exit__ ...
```

Then use `with write_on_change_file(...) as f:`.
The body of the `with` statement will be executed “instead of” the `yield`. Wrap the `yield` itself in a `try` block if you want to catch any exceptions that happen in the body.

The temporary file will always be properly closed (when its `with` block ends).

Comment: This is really nice.  I'm going to leave the question open for a little while in case this question produces any other good answers.

Comment: Using `@contextlib.contextmanager` is convenient, but there are still cases where it’s appropriate to use a class with manually defined `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods.  Do you have any advice on doing so?

Comment: Well, do it when it is more convenient – for example when the object needs to do more than just be a context manager (though in that case you should also consider adding a @contextlib.contextmanager method).

Comment: My only suggestion is to move the `self.temporary_file = tempfile.TemporaryFile('r+')` into the init statement from a symmetry point of view.

Answer (score 5):

`contextlib.contextmanager` works great for functions, but when I need a classes as context manager, I'm using the following util:

```
class ContextManager(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
  """Class which can be used as `contextmanager`."""

  def __init__(self):
    self.__cm = None

  @abc.abstractmethod
  @contextlib.contextmanager
  def contextmanager(self):
    raise NotImplementedError('Abstract method')

  def __enter__(self):
    self.__cm = self.contextmanager()
    return self.__cm.__enter__()

  def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
    return self.__cm.__exit__(exc_type, exc_value, traceback)
```

This allow to declare contextmanager classes with the generator syntax from `@contextlib.contextmanager`. It makes it much more natural to nest contextmanager, without having to manually call `__enter__` and `__exit__`. Example:

```
class MyClass(ContextManager):

  def __init__(self, filename):
    self._filename = filename

  @contextlib.contextmanager
  def contextmanager(self):
    with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as temp_file:
      yield temp_file
      ...  # Post-processing you previously had in __exit__


with MyClass('filename') as x:
  print(x)
```

I wish this was in the standard library...

Comment: @NeilG, as per @Zearin comment, there are cases where using a class instead of a function is required, in which case `contextlib.contextmanager` cannot be used. This util allow to use the `contextlib.contextmanager` generator syntax with a class. This makes it much more natural to nest contextmanagers without having to store `x.__enter__()` and manually call `x.__exit__()`

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't answer my question, which is about nesting context managers.  Also, whenever you implement `__enter__` and `__exit__`, you should always call super in case your class is used in cooperative inheritance.

Comment: @NeilG, I updated the code snippet to better match the question. Basically, it is the same answer as Petr Viktorin, but working with class.

Comment: Now this looks tasty. As far as I can tell, it lets us *directly* replace `with instance._hidden_ctxt1, instance._hidden_ctxt2, instance._hidden_ctxt3:` with merely `with instance:`, correct? (As opposed to using the exisiting stdlib decorator by which we could write `with instance.as_with():`, requiring the extra method call in the with clause)

Comment: ah, not quite, this only allows delegating to a single internal context. still, as a stdlib algo, i would think it wouldn't be so hard to check if the yielded value of `contextmanager()` is an iterable or not, so it should be perfectly doable.