# Handling instances of a context manager inside another context manager

Tags: python, contextmanager

How should a context manager created inside another context manager be handled in Python?

Example: suppose you have class `A` that acts as a context manager, and class `B` that also acts as a context manager. But class `B` instances will have to instantiate and use an instance of class `A`. I've gone through PEP 343 and this is the solution I thought of:

```
class A(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        # Acquire some resources here
        return self

    def __exit__(seplf, exception_type, exception, traceback):
        # Release the resources and clean up
        pass


class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()

    def __enter__(self):
        # Acquire some resources, but also need to "start" our instance of A
        self.a.__enter__()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exception_type, exception, traceback):
        # Release the resources, and make our instance of A clean up as well
        self.a.__exit__(exception_type, exception, traceback)
```

Is this the correct approach? Or am I missing some gotchas?

Comment: Down in the comments, you write "it's the same class that has references to instances of itself recursively." Could you provide either an example that demonstrates this or an excerpt from your code? It would help with crafting a proper solution.

Comment: Related: if you want **multiple** instances of B inside A, refer to [python - Pythonic way to compose context managers for objects owned by a class - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51649361/pythonic-way-to-compose-context-managers-for-objects-owned-by-a-class/77951805#77951805) .

Answer (score 20):

If you can use the `@contextlib.contextmanager` decorator your life gets a lot easier:

```
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def internal_cm():
    try:
        print "Entering internal_cm"
        yield None
        print "Exiting cleanly from internal_cm"
    finally:
        print "Finally internal_cm"


@contextlib.contextmanager
def external_cm():
    with internal_cm() as c:
        try:
            print "In external_cm_f", c
            yield [c]
            print "Exiting cleanly from external_cm_f", c
        finally:
            print "Finally external_cm_f", c


if "__main__" == __name__:
    with external_cm():
        print "Location A"
    print
    with external_cm():
        print "Location B"
        raise Exception("Some exception occurs!!")
```

Answer (score 9):

Alternatively, you could write your code like so:

```
with A() as a:
    with B(a) as b:
        # your code here
```

Another solution you might want to try could be this:

```
class A:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        pass

class B(A):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def __enter__(self):
        super().__enter__()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        super().__exit__(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)
```

After considering the explanation of your situation, this might be a better solution:

```
class Resource:

    def __init__(self, dependency=None):
        self.dependency = dependency
        # your code here

    def __enter__(self):
        if self.dependency:
            self.dependency.__enter__()
        # your code here
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        # your code here
        if self.dependency:
            self.dependency.__exit__(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)
```

I am not sure if the following implementation is correct, but `__exit__` must take proper care of exceptions. It is somewhat difficult for me to imagine how to recursively chain the calls while handling exceptions properly.

```
class Resource:

    def __init__(self, dependency=None):
        self.dependency = dependency
        self.my_init()

    def __enter__(self):
        if self.dependency:
            self.dependency.__enter__()
        return self.my_enter()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        suppress = False
        try:
            suppress = self.my_exit(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)
        except:
            exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        if suppress:
            exc_type = exc_val = exc_tb = None
        if self.dependency:
            suppress = self.dependeny.__exit__(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)
            if not supress:
                raise exc_val.with_traceback(exc_tb) from None
        return suppress

    def my_init(self):
        pass

    def my_enter(self):
        pass

    def my_exit(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        pass
```

Comment: Interesting. That could work too. The downside of this is that the user of our `B` class will have to create the instance of `A` and pass it to us. Plus, it would get more and more complicated if the chain of requirements is more than one level deep. But good idea for simple cases. Thank you.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower Your class-based approach is only viable if it really makes sense for B to be a sub-class of A. IMO that relationship shouldn't be created strictly to make nesting them as context managers easier, since it violates the "IS-A" principle of OO programming.

Comment: I agree with @dano. If it logically makes sense for `B` to be a subclass of `A` this is a very good solution. My example above is oversimplified. In my actual use-case, it's the same class that has references to instances of itself recursively (somewhat like a linked list), and so they all need to be released recursively. The inheritance idea would not work there.

Comment: @Sahand Assuming I understood your last comment correctly, the third example may be a better solution to your situation. It is important that the dependency's `__enter__` is executed before the current instance's, and the current instance's `__exit__` code should be run before the dependency's.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower Why is that important? In terms of data flow of my specific use case I see it more as the `A` instance that is inside `B` to be dependent on the instance of `B` as opposed to the other way around. So I'm curious about your rationale for it being important to have `A` enter before `B` and exit after. (To clarify, I am not disagreeing, mainly curious about reasoning.)

Comment: If your instance truly has a dependency (`a` in the first example), then its `__enter__` would have been called first before `b` was entered. Likewise, `b`'s `__exit__` will be called before `a`'s.

Comment: @Sahand The fourth example makes an attempt at respecting how `__exit__` methods are supposed to work. The return value must be accounted for along with any exceptions the method might raise. Trying to reimplement the `with` statement's machinery is slightly complicated. See [PEP 343](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) for its specifications.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of manual resource management in a contextmanager: The outer contextmanager manages the inner.

```
class Inner:

    def __enter__(self):
        print("<inner>")
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        print("</inner>")


class Outer:

    def __init__(self):
        self.inner = Inner()

    def __enter__(self):
        self.inner.__enter__()
        try:
            #raise RuntimeError("Suppose we fail here")
            print("<outer>")
            return self
        except Exception as e:
            self.inner.__exit__(None, None, None)
            raise e

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        print("</outer>")
        self.inner.__exit__(exc_type, exc_value, traceback)
```

Usage is as normal:

```
with Outer() as scope:
    #raise RuntimeError("Suppose we fail here")
    pass
```

The observant reader will notice that the inner contextmanager now becomes a pointless marionette puppet (since we are pulling its threads manually). So be it.

Comment: Depending on how you want to handle exceptions,  `__exit__`  might need to `return self.inner.__exit__(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on kuzzooroo's [top upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28401296/5080984) but applying it for Python 3+:

For convenience here is kuzzooroo's original code as Python 3 code (pretty much adding parenthesis for the `print` statements:

```py
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def internal_cm():
    try:
        print("Entering internal_cm")
        yield None
        print("Exiting cleanly from internal_cm")
    finally:
        print("Finally internal_cm")


@contextlib.contextmanager
def external_cm():
    with internal_cm() as c:
        try:
            print("In external_cm_f")
            yield [c]
            print("Exiting cleanly from external_cm_f")
        finally:
            print("Finally external_cm_f")

if "__main__" == __name__:
    with external_cm():
        print("Location A")
    with external_cm():
        print("Location B")
        raise Exception("Some exception occurs!!")
```

And here is the output of this script:

```
Entering internal_cm
In external_cm_f
Location A
Exiting cleanly from external_cm_f
Finally external_cm_f
Exiting cleanly from internal_cm
Finally internal_cm
Entering internal_cm
In external_cm_f
Location B
Finally external_cm_f
Finally internal_cm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 28, in <module>
    raise Exception("Some exception occurs!!")
Exception: Some exception occurs!!
```