# what is the pythonic way to inherit context manager

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, contextmanager

Python teaches us to do cleanup on objects using `__enter__` and `__exit__`.
What if i need to create an object which uses objects must use context managers? Imagine this:

```
from database1 import DB1
from database2 import DB2
```

Normally, they would be used as such:

```
with DB1() as db1, DB2() as db2:
    db1.do_stuff()
    db2.do_other_stuff()
```

Whatever happens, `db1` and `db2` will both run their `__exit__` function, and clean up the connection, flush, etc.

When i'd put all of this in a class, how would i do it? <strike>Is this right?</strike> This is obviously not right, the context manager for `db1` and `db2` runs at the end of the block, as pointed in comments.

```
class MyApp(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        with DB1() as self.db1, DB2() as self.db2:
            return self
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.db1.__exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
        self.db2.__exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
```

<strike>I even considered doing something like this:</strike> This looks like a good idea, actually (after some cleanup):

```
class MyApp(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.db1 = DB1()
        self.db2 = DB2()
    def __enter__(self):
        self.db1.__enter__()
        self.db2.__enter__()
        return self
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        try:
            self.db1.__exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
        except:
            pass
        try:
            self.db2.__exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
        except:
            pass
```

EDIT: Fixed the code.

Comment: Your first attempt doesn't make sense - the `with DB1() ...` block ends *before* `MyApp.__enter__` completes; `self.db1` will already have `__exit__`ed long before `MyApp.__exit__` starts.

Comment: Second option is almost good, and will be ok if you add exception handling (so that if second `__enter__` or first `__exit__` fails, the other connection does not hang. That said, consider [`contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager).

Comment: @jonrsharpe, i know that's why i asked in the first place.

Comment: Have you read e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/8720179/3001761?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pythonic way to compose context managers for objects owned by a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51649361/pythonic-way-to-compose-context-managers-for-objects-owned-by-a-class)

Answer (score 7):

I would go with the second solution but also handle database errors:

```
import sys

class MyApp(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.db1 = DB1()
        self.db2 = DB2()
    def __enter__(self):
        self.db1.__enter__()
        try:
            self.db2.__enter__()
        except:
            self.db1.__exit__(None, None, None) # I am not sure with None
            raise
        return self
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        try:
            self.db1.__exit__(type, value, traceback)
        finally:
            self.db2.__exit__(type, value, traceback)
```

The first one calls `__exit__` in `__enter__` because of `with` - so, does not work.

**EDIT:** Also check out the [answer by @Ming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31190181/1320237). In many cases it is shorter.

Comment: shouldn't you setup the variables to be none on the class?

Comment: Your `__enter__` function doesn't `return self`.

Comment: @user37203 Thanks, corrected that. @ JohnRuddell could you explain why?

Comment: in a context, `__init__` is run first, then `__enter__`. Maybe a confusion related to the run order?

Comment: the external `__exit__` methods also don't take a separate `self` argument when called. looks like a correction is probably waiting for edit approval as the edit queue is full

Answer (score 6):

Most context managers can just be written with using the `@contextmanager` decorator. You write a function with one yield, before the yield is your 'enter' function and after the yield is your 'exit' function. Due to the way generators are implemented if a yield is in a with statement then the with statement does not exit at the yield.

eg.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

class SomeContextManager:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __enter__(self):
        print("enter", self.name)
        return self
    def __exit__(self, ex_type, value, traceback):
        print("exit", self.name)

class SomeContextManagerWrapper:
    def __init__(self, *context_managers):
        self.context_managers = context_managers
    @property
    def names(self):
        return [cm.name for cm in self.context_managers]

@contextmanager
def context_manager_combiner():
    print("context_manager_combiner entering")
    with SomeContextManager("first") as a, SomeContextManager("second") as b:
        yield SomeContextManagerWrapper(a, b)
    print("context_manager_combiner exiting")

with context_manager_combiner() as wrapper:
    print("in with statement with:", wrapper.names)
```

outputs:

```
context_manager_combiner entering
enter first
enter second
in with statement with: ['first', 'second']
exit second
exit first
context_manager_combiner exiting
```

Comment: This is the best answer, but i need something which i can apply in a class instantiation. I'm not really sure how to do that with `contextmanager`.

Comment: You can return a class in the yield statement that wraps your database, which can have the associated methods for manipulating the databases.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you are trying to achieve overall. One possibility is to construct the individual context managers, then combine them with the standard library's [contextlib.nested](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.nested). This will give you a single object which behaves like your example `MyApp` but utilizes the existing standard library in a DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) fashion.

Comment: This is nice! Could you add source code? Is it possible to use a class with this?